# How to pass Json array to servlet

Tags: javascript, json, servlets

[DUPICATE]

<strike>This My POST JSON Code</strike>

```
var data_create = JSON.stringify($("#form_create_delegate").serializeArray());

        alert("isi data_create" + data_create);

//        console.log(data_create)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "formCreateDelegationServlet",
            dataType: "json",
            data:data:{JSONFile:data_create},
            success: function (response) {  }


        });
```

THIS MY Result JSON

```
JSONFile:[{"name":"id_form_delegate","value":"1"},{"name":"merchant","value":"AMBHARA HOTEL TERBAIK"},{"name":"citty","value":"JAKARTA PUSAT"},{"name":"addrs","value":"JL. DIPONEGORO NO.  1J"},{"name":"province_merchant","value":"DKI JAKARTA"},{"name":"mid_merchant[]","value":"1"},{"name":"tid_merchant[]","value":"1"},{"name":"mid_merchant[]","value":"2"},{"name":"tid_merchant[]","value":"2"}]
```

How to remove property "name" and "value" from my JsonArray

I want to make a format like this

```
[{"merchant":"AMBHARA HOTEL TERBAIK","citty":"JAKARTA PUSAT"}]
```

this my servlet code

```
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(request.getParameter("JSONFile"));

            merchant = jsonObject.getString("merchant");
            city = jsonObject.getString("city");
            addrs = jsonObject.getString("addrs");
            province_merchant = jsonObject.getString("province_merchant");
            tid = jsonObject.getString("tid_merchant");
            mid = jsonObject.getString("tid_merchant");
//            
            System.out.println("nama_merchant: " + nama_merchant);
            System.out.println("kota_merchant: " + kota_merchant);
            System.out.println("alamat_merchant: " + alamat_merchant);
            System.out.println("province_merchant: " + province_merchant);
            System.out.println("mid: " + mid);
            System.out.println("tid: " + tid);
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: if you delete both, you get empty objects.

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Nothing will be left if you get rid of those properties from your object

Comment: You question is not clear. Maybe you want an array of arrays like this `[["id_form_delegate","1"],["merchant",""AMBHARA HOTEL TERBAIK"]]` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of keys and just keep values as arrays, you can use Array.map like this

```js
var input=[{"name":"id_form_delegate","value":"1"},{"name":"merchant","value":"AMBHARA HOTEL TERBAIK"},{"name":"citty","value":"JAKARTA PUSAT"},{"name":"addrs","value":"JL. DIPONEGORO NO.  1J"},{"name":"province_merchant","value":"DKI JAKARTA"},{"name":"mid_merchant[]","value":"1"},{"name":"tid_merchant[]","value":"1"},{"name":"mid_merchant[]","value":"2"},{"name":"tid_merchant[]","value":"2"}]

var result = input.map(function (obj) {return [obj.name, obj.value]})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

You can make it dynamic, so that it just works with any property and not only "name" and "value", using `Object.keys` (not supported in MSIE pre 9). But beware that you lose control on the order of values in output.

```js
input=[{"name":"id_form_delegate","value":"1"},{"name":"merchant","value":"AMBHARA HOTEL TERBAIK"},{"name":"citty","value":"JAKARTA PUSAT"},{"name":"addrs","value":"JL. DIPONEGORO NO.  1J"},{"name":"province_merchant","value":"DKI JAKARTA"},{"name":"mid_merchant[]","value":"1"},{"name":"tid_merchant[]","value":"1"},{"name":"mid_merchant[]","value":"2"},{"name":"tid_merchant[]","value":"2"}]

result = input.map(function (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {return obj[key]})
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: @AdamAzad it's not what OP is asking, but it's an interesting task